# I want to show hsl live stream video on my next js project but it is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

const VideoPlayer =  () => {

return (

<ReactPlayer

```
    url='http://202.59.208.114/hls/'
    controls
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
  />
</div>
```

);
}

export default VideoPlayer;

i tried those code and not working